# link syntax error using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, href

I wrote a basic loop in php that worked for what I wanted, but now I am trying to add a link as well but cannot get the syntax right and the examples I have found the syntax does not work for me and keep getting errors. If anyone could show me where I am going wrong that would be amazing. Thank you in advance whether you are able to help or not!

The code that is throwing errors is

```
<a href=\"addcomment.php?id="'. $row['postid'] .'\">' "Add Comment" '</a>");
```

and the full code is.

```
<?php
    include("connect.php"); //connect to database
    //create query
    $get_messages_query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM `blogposts`
        ORDER BY `postid` DESC 
        LIMIT 5
        ");
    //Homepage should have last 5 blog posts this will take the //last 5 entered into the database and put them into an //array

    $get_messages_query->execute();
    //executes query above

    while($row = $get_messages_query->fetch())
    {
        $blog_post_history .=
        '<div class="post" id="post">
            <h1>'. $row['title'] .' </h1>
            <h2>' . $row['author'] . '</h2>
            <p>'. $row['content'] . '</p>
            <a href=\"addcomment.php?id="'. $row['postid'] .'\">' "Add Comment" '</a>");

        </div>';
    }

    // while loop that takes info from db query and puts the //information in its own div with title andauthor having a //unique heading for css as well as a p for the content of //the blog. This loop puts the information in //$blog_post_history which is called upon in the div code 
    //below
?>
```

Comment: PDO has absolutely nothing to do with whatever links or HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with quotes around here

```
$blog_post_history .=
    '<div class="post" id="post">
        <h1>'. $row['title'] .' </h1>
        <h2>' . $row['author'] . '</h2>
        <p>'. $row['content'] . '</p>
        <a href="addcomment.php?id='. $row['postid'] .'">Add Comment</a>
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $get_messages_query->fetch())
{
    $blog_post_history .=
    '<div class="post" id="post">
        <h1>'. $row['title'] .' </h1>
        <h2>' . $row['author'] . '</h2>
        <p>'. $row['content'] . '</p>
        <a href="addcomment.php?id='. $row['postid'] .'"> Add Comment </a>
    </div>';
}
```